# Convert list<MapObject> into JSONObject

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a list of `RequestBodyObject`, something like this:

```
List<RequestBodyObject> body = new ArrayList<>();
```

`RequestBodyObject` is something like this:

```
Map<String, String> requestBodyElements;
```

I am creating HashMap something like below:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    
    Map<String, String> requestBodyElements = new HashMap<>();
    List<RequestBodyObject> body = new ArrayList<>();
    
    requestBodyElements.put("xyz", "abc");
    requestBodyElements.put("def", "pqr");
    
    RequestBodyObject requestBodyObject = new RequestBodyObject();
    requestBodyObject.setRequestBodyElements(requestBodyElements);
    body.add(requestBodyObject);
    
    params.put("key1", body);
    params.put("key2", "value2");
```

Now I want to convert it to JSONObject to pass as a request body in a `REST` call

I am trying to do something like this but not able to pass Map as a List

```
private static JSONObject getJsonFromMap(Map<String, Object> map) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        Object value = map.get(key);
        if (value instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            value = getJsonFromMap((Map<String, Object>) value);
        }
        jsonData.put(key, value);
    }
    return jsonData;
}
```

Desired JSONObject is :

```
{
   "format":"HTML",
   "requestBodyElements":[
    {
       "abc":"zyv",
       "def":"ghi"
     }]
  }
```

My function was able to make it something like:

```
{
   "format":"HTML",
   "requestBodyElements":
    {
       "abc":"zyv",
       "def":"ghi"
     }
  }
```

I need to convert `requestBodyElements` into array of elements. Any help much appreciated

Comment: I think you need JSONArray for that.

Comment: @sergey-vasnev: Actually I want an array of object. Any code snippet, is much appreciated

Comment: What exactly Json library you are using?

Comment: I am using org.json.simple but I am flexible to use any other like GSON etc

Answer (score 1):

There is a class JSONArray which can be used to represent an Array `[]` json value. I think you can consider using it. Code can look like this:

```
private static JSONArray getJsonFromMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        Object value = map.get(key);
        if (value instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            value =  getJsonFromMap((Map<String, Object>) value);
        }
        jsonData.put(key, value);
    }
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.add(jsonData);
    return jsonArray;
}
```